# Valgrind error - Conditional Jump or Move Depends on uninitialised Values

Tags: c, pointers

Can't figure out what's the problem with this bit of code and why I am getting this error.
c:106 is the line I marked. I'm taking it that the problem is the the n value in the null check on the previous line.
Which means whatever is being passed from the table is the problem? I think.
The second function is where the table is loaded. Don't see any problems there though.
Just lost.

```
    ==6929== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
    ==6929==    at 0x4012C1: unload (dictionary.c:106)
    ==6929==    by 0x400E09: main (speller.c:152)
    ==6929==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
    ==6929==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
    ==6929==    by 0x4011B5: load (dictionary.c:71)
    ==6929==    by 0x400964: main (speller.c:40)
    ==6929== 


// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 676;

// Hash table
node *table[N];
int wc = 0;
// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    char c[LENGTH + 1];
    node *n =table[hash(word)];
    while (n != NULL)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(n->word, word) ==0)
        {
            return true;
            
        }
        n = n->next;
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    int tally = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (word[j] != '\0')
    {
        char letter = tolower(word[j]);
        tally += letter - 'a';
        j++;
    }
    return tally % N;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if(f == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    char t[LENGTH + 1];
    
    while(fscanf(f, "%s\n", t) != EOF)
    {
        node *n = NULL;
        n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
       strcpy(n->word, t);
       int x = hash(t);
      
      if (table[x] == NULL)
      {
          table[x] = n;
      }
      else
      {
          n->next = table[x];
          table[x] = n;
      }
       wc++;
    }
    fclose(f);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return wc;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    node *n = NULL;
     for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        n = table[i];
        while(n != NULL )
        {
            node *x = n;
            n = n->next;
            free(x);
        }
        table[i] = NULL;
    }
    free(n);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: By the way, it's not `c:106`, it's `dictionary.c:106`

Comment: You haven't initialised the node. Use calloc instead of malloc to initialise it with all zeros, or initialize the members one by one.

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  Amongst many other problems, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.

Comment: the macro `LENGTH` is not defined in the posted code.

Comment: Is there a `speller.h` or `dictionary.h` file that you forgot to post?

Comment: regarding: `while(fscanf(f, "%s\n", t)  != EOF )`  1) always check for a positive, not EOF.  2) always limit the length of `%s` to 1 less than the length of the input buffer.  3) do not use trailing 'white space' in the format string.  Suggest: `while(fscanf(f, "%" LENGTH "s", t)  == 1 )`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }`  when an error occurs, inform the user.  Suggest inserting, before the `return` statement: `perror( "malloc failed" );`  as that will output to `stderr`, both the error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.

Comment: regarding: `const unsigned int N = 676;` and `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)`  results in a comparison between a 'signed' and a 'unsigned' value

Comment: regarding: `int wc = 0;` and `unsigned int size(void)
{
    return wc;`  results in a conflict between a signed variable and a unsigned returned type

Comment: regarding: `unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    int tally = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (word[j] != '\0')
    {
        char letter = tolower(word[j]);
        tally += letter - 'a';
        j++;
    }
    return tally % N;`  This results in a 'signed' value being returned when a 'unsigned' value is expected

Comment: regarding: `char letter = tolower(word[j]);`  The function: `tolower()` returns an `int`, not a `char`

Comment: the function: `check()` calls function: `hash()`, but function: `hash()` is not yet defined.  Suggest either reversing the order of those functions or insert a prototype for `hash()` before `main()`

Comment: in function: `check()` there is the declaration: `char c[LENGTH + 1];`  but the variable is never used.  Suggest removing that variable

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: (the compiler does not care) please consistently indent the code: Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: regarding; `unsigned int hash(const char *word)` and `int x = hash(t);`  This is trying assign a 'signed' value from a 'unsigned' value

Comment: regarding: `const unsigned int N = 676;` and `node *table[N];`   This is not C++ so this does not compile. Suggest `#define N 676`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: Please use meaningful variable names.  Names like `t`, `n` `f` are meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: in function `unload()` regarding; `free( table );`  The `table` was never dynamically allocated so cannot be passed to `free()`

Answer (score 1):

When valgrind says that an error is at a specific line it can sometimes actually be at the previous or the next line.

This is the case here. At line 105, you have the line `n != NULL`. `n` hasn't be initialized thus you have an undefined behavior. Please check how `table` is initialized (not shown in your code).

The most likely causes for your errors are: You malloc'ed your array but haven't initialized it or you initialized the values up to `X<N` then you access your array from index `0` to `N` leading to incorrect access for `]X,N]`.

EDIT: After you updated your code, it becomes obvious that it contains at least these issues:

- `table` is initialized with a loop `while(fscanf(f, "%s\n", t) != EOF)`. = but is parsed with `while(fscanf(f, "%s\n", t) != EOF)`. Let say that there is X field in your field, what if `X<N` ? `X>N`?
- `if (table[x] == NULL){table[x] = n;}` `table[x]->next` remains uninitialized

**Should I use calloc for table?**

This is a possibility. But you could also make it work with properly initializing you array with malloc. Both possibility are viable.

Overall, I think that your code is unnecesarily complex and  can be dramatically simplified. You might want to refactor it instead of just correcting the errors.

Comment: `node *n = table[i];`?? (now what `table[i]` is -- and I assume a global pointer allocated with `malloc` -- may be the issue)

Comment: I added the rest of the code.
Should I do node *table[] = calloc(N, node)?

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. incorporates most of the comments I made to the OPs question

and now, the proposed code;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


#define LENGTH 50

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
#define N 676

// Hash table
node *table[N] = {NULL};
unsigned wc = 0;


// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    unsigned tally = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (word[j] != '\0')
    {
        int letter = tolower(word[j]);
        tally += (unsigned)letter - 'a';
        j++;
    }
    return tally % N;
}


// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
   // char c[LENGTH + 1];
    node *n =table[hash(word)];
    while (n != NULL)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(n->word, word) ==0)
        {
            return true;
            
        }
        n = n->next;
    }
    return false;
}


// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if(f == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    char t[ LENGTH + 1 ];
    
    while( fscanf( f, "%49s", t ) == 1 )
    {
        node *n = NULL;
        n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        
        strcpy( n->word, t );
        unsigned x = hash(t);
      
        if (table[x] == NULL)
        {
            table[x] = n;
        }
      
        else
        {
            n->next = table[x];
            table[x] = n;
        }
      
        wc++;
    }
    fclose(f);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return wc;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
void unload(void)
{   
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        node *n = table[i];
        while(n != NULL )
        {
            node *x = n;
            n = n->next;
            free(x);
        }
        table[i] = NULL;
    }
    //free( table );
    //return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created a **pointer** somewhere in the code that you have **not initialized**
To fix it, you have to give the pointer an initial value, even *NULL*.

For example, the load function in my code is as follows:

```
// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // Open dictionary
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Navigate dictionary word by word
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) == 1)
    {
        // Initialize new node
        node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (new_node == NULL)
        {
            // Free other nodes in table
            unload();
            return false;
        }

        // Set word of new node
        strcpy(new_node->word, word);

        // Calculate hash code of word
        int hash_code = hash(word);

        // Check first node of hash table
        if (table[hash_code] == NULL)
        {
            table[hash_code] = new_node;
            new_node->next = NULL;
            word_count++;
        }
        else
        {
            new_node->next = table[hash_code];
            table[hash_code] = new_node;
            word_count++;
        }
    }

    // Close dictionary file
    fclose(file);
    return true;
}
```

Pay attention to the ***if(table(hash_code) == NULL)*** statement.
i ***new_node->next = NULL;*** I added.